# Do I need to fill out the Austrian pre-travel-clearance for transiting through Vienna International Airport?

Tags: transit, paperwork, covid-19, austria

I have booked a flight to the UK transiting through Vienna International Airport, and recently I received an email (from the airline) asking me to fill out pre-travel-clearance for Austria, which includes address of quarantine (Austria), but I'm not staying in or entering Austria, so I'm not sure if I need to fill out this form.

Comment: Which airline? What did they say about filling in the form when you asked them?

Comment: It is Austrian Airlines, I tried calling the local office here, however they didn't answer the call, and there are not many details on Internet for transiting on the airport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the form website https://entry.ptc.gv.at/en.html

Press "One or more of the exceptions mentioned in § 7(1) or § 8 of the COVID-19 entry regulation are applicable to my entry." and it'll say you're exempt. Furthermore, the site then won't even let you press the button to submit (it also requires an Austrian address, which is obviously not applicable).

At the airport, follow the signs for the D/G gates. You may face a military checkpoint. If so, show your passport/ID and say you're transiting to the UK, and show your ticket if asked.

Comment: military checkpoint in the airport? Are they currently assisting the police, which are ordinarily responsible?

Comment: @JakeDot The military does the entry checks as per COVID restrictions, both for Schengen and non-Schengen arrivals. For non-Schengen arrivals, the regular border control (police) follows 10 metres after

Comment: Thank you very much! I will stick to this and keep my ticket near me as a proof.

Comment: @someone12321 Saw you're flying TO the UK. Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks again, I'm arriving from non-Schengen country, so I guess I will undergo the regular border control after telling the military that I'm leaving for the UK.

Comment: @someone12321 No, there's no regular border control for non-Schengen -> non-Schengen transfers. So once in the terminal, just look out for the signs to the D/G gates and follow those (even if no one else is)

Comment: I see, I forgot UK is not-Schengen. Thanks a lot once again!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Pre-Travel Clearance website](https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/en/themen/coronavirus_in_oesterreich/pre-travel-clearance.html) of the Austrian government, you are exempt from filling out the form.

> In accordance with Section 7 para. 1 and Section 8 of the
> COVID-19-Einreiseverordnung registration with the pre-travel clearance
> form is not required: […]
>
> When entry is related to other exceptions in accordance with Section 8
> para. 1 and Section 8 para. 2: […]
>
> **In the case of transit passengers** (they must also leave the country
> promptly)

On arrival in Vienna, you might be required to show evidence for your (immediate) continuing flight out of VIE.